# Pandas: Merging one-to-many with date interval

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Last time some people helped me already, which I'm very thankfull for. But I still have another question.

I'm working on a big data set of thousands of selling records. And I have the customer special price deals. There are way more transactions than price deals. Now: I want to append the price deals to the customer selling records.

- Customer = Customer
- Article = Article
- Date_from <= Paydate <= Date_untill

So, I want the following Columns: [ 'Customer', 'Article', 'Paydate', 'Price']
And Paydate has to be in between Date_from and Date_untill.

I tried the following code, but this doesnt work:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['Customer', 'Article', df2['Date_from']<=df1['Paydate']<=df2['Date_untill']])
```

A part of the dataframes I use are:

```
array([['B001', Timestamp('2020-01-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2021-01-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2022-01-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-01-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-01-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-01-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-01-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-01-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-01-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-01-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-01-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-01-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-01-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-01-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-01-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-02-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-02-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-02-13 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-02-13 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-02-21 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-03-04 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-03-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-03-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-03-17 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-03-25 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-03-31 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-04-08 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-04-17 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-04-21 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-04-29 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-05-06 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-05-08 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-05-12 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-05-15 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-06-04 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-06-09 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-06-15 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-06-18 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-06-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-07-08 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-07-15 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-07-20 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-07-22 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-07-29 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-08-05 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-08-14 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-08-19 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-08-21 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-09-04 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-09-04 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-09-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-09-18 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-09-18 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-09-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-09-29 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-10-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-10-08 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-10-14 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-10-21 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-10-28 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-10-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-11-09 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-11-12 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-11-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-11-18 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-11-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-12-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-12-11 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-12-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-12-18 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-12-23 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B001', Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-01-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-01-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-01-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-01-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-01-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-01-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-01-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-01-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-01-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-01-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-01-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-01-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-02-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-02-13 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-02-13 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-02-17 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-02-21 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-02-21 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-02-29 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-03-06 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-03-06 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-03-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-03-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-03-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-03-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-03-23 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-03-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-03-26 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-04-17 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-04-21 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-04-21 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-04-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-05-06 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-05-06 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-05-19 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-05-27 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-06-03 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-06-09 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-06-22 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-07-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-07-20 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-07-27 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-07-29 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-07-31 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-08-05 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-08-14 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-08-14 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-08-14 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-08-28 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-09-04 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-09-09 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-09-11 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-09-18 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-09-18 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-09-18 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-09-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-09-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-10-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-10-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-10-09 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-10-21 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-10-21 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-10-28 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-10-28 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-10-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-11-05 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-11-12 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-11-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-11-26 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-11-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-12-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-12-11 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-12-11 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-12-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-12-23 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B003', Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B101', Timestamp('2020-02-13 00:00:00'), 987654321],
   ['B101', Timestamp('2020-10-26 00:00:00'), 987654321],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-01-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-01-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-01-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-01-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-01-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-01-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-01-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-01-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-01-20 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-01-20 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-01-20 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-01-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-01-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-01-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-01-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-01-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-01-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-02-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-02-13 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-02-17 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-02-17 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-02-21 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-02-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-02-29 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-03-06 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-03-06 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-03-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-03-19 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-03-25 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-03-31 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-04-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-04-08 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-04-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-04-17 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-04-17 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-04-28 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-04-29 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-04-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-05-06 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-05-15 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-05-27 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-05-29 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-06-03 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-06-05 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-06-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-06-18 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-06-22 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-06-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-06-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-07-15 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-07-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-07-20 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-07-22 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-07-29 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-07-31 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-08-14 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-08-14 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-08-19 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-08-26 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-08-28 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-09-04 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-09-09 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-09-18 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-09-18 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-09-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-09-29 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-10-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-10-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-10-09 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-10-14 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-10-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-10-21 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-10-28 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-11-05 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-11-09 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-11-12 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-11-18 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-11-26 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-11-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-12-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-12-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-12-11 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-12-11 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-12-23 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-12-28 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B105', Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-01-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-01-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-01-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-01-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-01-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-01-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-01-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-01-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-01-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-01-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-01-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-01-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-01-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-01-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-01-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-02-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-02-13 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-02-13 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-03-04 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-03-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-03-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-03-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-03-26 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-04-03 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-04-21 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B200', Timestamp('2020-04-28 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-01-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-01-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-01-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-01-31 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-01-31 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-01-31 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-01-31 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-01-31 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-01-31 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-02-13 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-02-18 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-02-21 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-02-29 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-03-10 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-03-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-03-31 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-04-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-04-21 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-04-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-04-29 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-05-06 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-05-12 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-05-15 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-05-27 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-06-03 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-06-05 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-06-15 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-06-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-07-13 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-07-20 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-07-27 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-08-14 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-08-14 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-08-21 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-08-31 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-09-18 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-09-18 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-09-18 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-09-24 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-10-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-10-09 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-10-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-10-26 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-10-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-10-30 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-11-05 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-11-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-11-26 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-12-07 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-12-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-12-16 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-12-23 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00'), 123456789],
   ['B500', Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00'), 123456789]],
  dtype=object)
```

and

```
array([['B001', 123456789, Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
    Timestamp('2020-04-16 00:00:00'), 21.058],
   ['B001', 123456789, Timestamp('2020-04-16 00:00:00'),
    Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00'), 25.34],
   ['B003', 123456789, Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
    Timestamp('1900-01-11 00:00:00'), 23.058],
   ['B003', 123456789, Timestamp('2020-04-12 00:00:00'),
    Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00'), 27.34],
   ['B101', 987654321, Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
    Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00'), 40.48],
   ['B105', 123456789, Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
    Timestamp('1900-01-25 00:00:00'), 26.058],
   ['B105', 123456789, Timestamp('2020-04-26 00:00:00'),
    Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00'), 30.34],
   ['B200', 123456789, Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
    Timestamp('1900-02-09 00:00:00'), 28.058],
   ['B200', 123456789, Timestamp('2020-05-11 00:00:00'),
    Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00'), 32.34],
   ['B500', 123456789, Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
    Timestamp('1900-01-10 00:00:00'), 30.058],
   ['B500', 123456789, Timestamp('2020-04-11 00:00:00'),
    Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00'), 34.34]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for sharing the arrays above, but could you share df1 and df2 (or a sample from both) please? That'll make debugging easier :)

Comment: The examples you included are numpy arrays, not dataframes. You use `df1.head(50).to_clipboard(excel=False)` to copy the content to clipboard and then paste the output here.